# Rspec: How to test that substring appears in string a certain amount of times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Trying to use the `.exactly` method but it doesn't seem to work here.

```
expect(data).to include(purchase.email).exactly(3).times
```

This produces the error:

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `exactly' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Include:0x007f85c7e71108>
 # ./spec/models/csv_generator_spec.rb:34:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/models/csv_generator_spec.rb:18:in `each'
 # ./spec/models/csv_generator_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Does anyone know how I would test that a substring appears a certain amount of times in a string?

Comment: This seems to work in the current version (3.12) now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [`scan`](http://devdocs.io/ruby/string#method-i-scan) method, which returns an array of matches. Then you just check the size of the array:

```
expect(data.scan(purchase.email).size).to eq(3)
```

An alternative is this syntax:

```
expect(data.scan(purchase.email)).to have(3).items

expect(data.scan(purchase.email)).to have_exactly(3).items
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this using the repeated regex pattern like this,

```
r = %r{(#{purchase.email}).*\1.*\1.*}
```

Then, expect use regexp matcher in rspec as,

```
match = data.match(r)
expect(data).to match(r)
expect(match[1]).to be_eql(purchase.email)
```

Comment: But this does not deal with the number of repetitions. So, the solution proposed by @fivedigit is more succinct.